# Copy EBS Snapshots to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Is there anyway to copy EBS Snapshot from one region to another region in AWS (other than Console option and and using aws lambda)? I tried using AWS Lambda and boto3 but only 20 snapshots can be in pending state when you are performing copy_snapshost operation. I have close to 5,000 snapshots in us-east-1 and wanted  to copy the same to us-west-1. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Even supposing was another tool, the limit of 20 concurrent copies would still apply, as it will use the same API (potentially with a different SDK) which you use for your lambda or which is the Console backend.

That being said, even though it's listed as a ***not adjustable*** on the [EBS Service Limits page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ebs-service.html#limits_ebs) according to this announcement you [can raise a support request for a higher limit][2].

[2]: [https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ebs-increases-concurrent-snapshot-copy-limits-to-20-snapshots-per-destination-region/#:~:text=You%20can%20now%20copy%20up,(US)%20and%20China](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ebs-increases-concurrent-snapshot-copy-limits-to-20-snapshots-per-destination-region/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20copy%20up,(US)%20and%20China)).